# read_delim: Data missing when reading compressed file

Tags: r

I recently encoutered a problem using read_delim to read a tar.gz file.
Basically, if the file is uncompressed before using the fonction, I have a normal output. For specific reasons, i need to use compressed files (mainly because I can't use a function to untar using the free version of RStudio, I can only do it when I'm logged in the server and using R in my shell)

But when i'm reading the same file uncompressed, I have one more row at the end (full of NA's), and more importantly the first row of the first column is empty, quick exemple:

```
txt <- read_delim("/path/file.txt", delim="\177", col_names = F)
```

Will give me a txt var with Y obs of x variables and all rows well formated

```
tar <- read_delim("/path/file.tar.gz", delim="\177", col_names = F)
```

Will give me a tar var with Y + 1 obs of x variables and a first row missing the X1 (it's an empty string "")

Hope you can help with my problem, and thank you in advance !

Milo

Comment: can you supply some sample data or a link to a .tar file that gives you this error?

Comment: That's the main problem, my data is sensitive so I can't send any files (and it's impossible to anonymise and recreate in the same conditions).

Comment: I understand, does something like Tableau's GlobalSuperstore data represent your data? The only way to help is to give us some sample data to go off of. You could also post your question here as well: https://community.rstudio.com

Comment: I got rid off the problem by remaking the untar command with specific options so i don't have rights issue, so it's no longer a problem. Thank you for your help !